# Echo Session Object in Foreach Loop

Tags: php, foreach

Here is my issue.

Session Array:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$item_id] = array('Quantity' => $item_quantity,
        'Price' => $item_total,
        'Item' => $item_id,
    );
```

Foreach Loop:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value)
{
echo $key['Quantity'];
```

I am trying to access Quantity or Item with my foreach. What am I doing wrong? Currently nothing is showing when I echo $key['Quantity], but it does echo the $item_id when I do echo $key

Comment: your looking for `echo $value['Quantity'];`

Comment: @cmorrissey I swear sometimes I don't use my head, that was too obvious. Post your answer so I can mark it.

Comment: When in doubt, do `var_dump($_SESSION);`